# INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController displayed always in English

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, siri, sirishortcuts

I've added **Siri Shortcuts** to my app and everything works fine, except for `INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController` that is always displayed in English and not with device language. 
Is a bug or we have to configure the translated strings somewhere?

Here is how I start the controller:

```
if let inShortcut = INShortcut(intent: intent) {
  inShortcut.intent?.suggestedInvocationPhrase = phrase
  let viewController = INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController(shortcut: inShortcut)
  viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
  viewController.delegate = self
  self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This issue happens only on iOS13 (on iOS12 the controller is displayed correctly).

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved on iOS 14.